# Cannot install Apple Enterprise application

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, apple-developer

I have an Enterprise app that until recently has been installing and working fine. Recently, I've been trying to install it but I am unable to do so. At first I thought it was the new rule that you needed to have two-factor authentication in the developer account. But I added the authentication and I still can't install.

What happens when installing is, it shows a progress bar that says "Loading". Then at some point it says "Installing", but almost immediately after it says "Installing" the progress bar disappears and the icon goes dark. Sometimes it shows a message saying that the app couldn't be installed and gives the option of retrying or done.

Furthermore, the app DOES install in some devices. I have confirmed that it installs on three devices, which is weird enough. I have no idea what could be causing this. If anyone can shed some light on this I will be forever grateful as I am losing my mind over this. I should add that the app was made in Ionic Framework and, like I said at the beginning, everything has been working perfectly until now.

EDIT: Another interesting point is that I tried running the app from XCode directly to my iPad and it is installing perfectly. It is only when I download it from my Enterprise link that it fails, and only on certain devices so far.

Comment: When was the last time it was built?  Has the embedded provisioning profile expired?  Have you accessed the device logs from the failing devices to see if there are any relevant messages?

Comment: Hi! It was last built like 3 weeks ago, but I built it again yesterday with no changes to the code. I don’t think the provisioning profile has expired. I checked the certificates and they are valid. About the logs, how would I be able to check them? I was trying to find a way to do this but had no luck. Thanks!

Comment: You can access the device console through the devices window in Xcode

Answer (score 1):

As per your question What I understand that you are running app from xcode and it runs on certain devices, but if you prepare a build it won't install in iOS devices right?

If it is right then follow these steps, may be this will sort issue for you.

1. If you run the app directly from xcode use development profile in code signing.
2. If you prepare build for enterprise edition use distribution profile and prepare the build. When you preparing build via archive then using option distribution, select the enterprise mode for preparing the build. may be this will sort your issue.

Before doing this, clean the project.

** I am considering that you have all the updated certificates, profiles and account.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already do use the Enterprise option when building my app. I did just try using the distribution profile when archiving, but it says that I have to switch to manual signing instead of automatic signing.